# Django Class-based Views - ListView if User Is Authenticated, FormView if User is Not, Same URL

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

When a visitor is logged out and visits my homepage, I want them to see a registration form. When the user logs in, they will be redirected back to the homepage, but it will show a listview-*like* view.

Is the best way to achieve this to subclass both `ListView` and `FormView` and override each method necessary to get the behavior I want? Or is there a better way? Checking if the user is authenticated in each method doesn't seem like the Django way to do this. Hoping there's a smart design pattern approach for doing this that I don't know about.

```
class HomepageView(ListView, FormView):

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return ['homepage/loggedin_index.html']
        else:
            return ['homepage/loggedout_index.html']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            ...
        else:
            ...

    def ... and so on
```

**My must-have requirement** is that the URL for both logged-in and logged-out users must resolve to the root URL since it's a homepage.

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomepageView

app_name = 'homepage'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomepageView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a CreateListView that do what you want. And then you can change its `form` to the one you want.